# ag-grid: how to add button in master detail template

Tags: angular5, ag-grid

I am using master/detail in ag-grid. I want a save button in detailed section after all rows. I am able to do that using template, but its not firing the event. I think its just a template and don't work for event. Can you please suggest me how can I add button in detailed section

here is my code

```
columnDefs: [
    {
        headerName: "CompanyName",
        field: "CompanyName",
        cellRenderer: "agGroupCellRenderer"
    }
],
groupDefaultExpanded: 0,
detailRowHeight: 200,
detailCellRendererParams: {
    detailGridOptions: {
        columnDefs: [                            
                    {
                        headerName: "Name",
                        field: "Name",
                        cellRenderer: "agGroupCellRenderer"
                    },
                    {
                        headerName: "Age",
                        field: "Age",
                        suppressFilter: true,
                    },
                    {
                        headerName: "Gender",
                        field: "Gender",
                        suppressFilter: true,
                    }
        ],
        onGridReady: function (params: any) {
            params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
        }
    },
    getDetailRowData: function (params: any) {
        params.successCallback(params.data.ChannelComponentsVm);
    },
      template:
      '<div style="height: 100%;">' +
      '<div ref="eDetailGrid" style="height: 90%;"></div>' +
      '<div style="height: 10%;"> <button (click)="saveEmployeeDetails()">Save</button> </div>' +
      '</div>'          
}
```

I cannot use it in cell renderer as the button is not in column. It should be at the end of the child grid.

```
-> parent row
   -> child row1
   -> child row2
   -> child row3
          Save button
```

How to add save button at the end of detailed rows

Comment: did you find any solution? even I need to add button and its click event. Button is showing but click event is not working.

Answer (score 2):

```js
// get ag grid template ref
@ViewChild('agGrid') agGrid: TemplateRef < any > ; 

// attach the click listener on row group opened grid event.
// don't forget to clean up this listener on destroy component event or somewhere in the code
rowGroupOpened(params: any) {
    var saveButton = this.agGrid["_nativeElement"].querySelector(`#saveDetailsButton`);

    if (saveButton) {
      saveButton.addEventListener('click',this.saveEmployeeDetails.bind(this));
    }
}


saveEmployeeDetails(): void {
    console.log('save button clicked');
}
```

Comment: This is one of the way. It works!. If anyone gets better answer please post it. Compilation of template string is not happening here. thats y it acts just like static string and not a template string. Need to build it on our own like adding dynamic component.

Comment: Does this require the button tag to have id="saveDetailsButton" ?

Answer (score 0):

vinoth's answer has the right idea, but I wanted to give a more complete answer shown a slightly different way. To start with, I had the same issue with the event not firing - this is due to lifecycle events and how things are compiled. If you are using a template (as shown in the question) then you cannot put the onClick event in the HTML in the template, you have to instead do it in TypeScript/JavaScript in the .ts file.

In your HTML where you define the ag-grid div, assign the action method `rowGroupOpened`. This should be in your HTML file, or possibly in your .ts file (not in the template in grid definitions).

```
(rowGroupOpened)="rowGroupOpened($event)"
```

In your .ts file, define the rowGroupOpened event.

```
RowGroupOpened(params: any) {
    //below pass the id of your button/div used in your template
    const buttonDiv = document.getElementById('saveButton');
    if (buttonDiv){
        buttonDiv.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            this.myButtonClickMethod();
        });
    }
}

myButtonClickMethod() {
    //do something
}
```

Your button in the template string should have an id like this:

```
<button id="saveButton">Save</button>
```

This way when one of your detail grids expanded it will attach the onClick method at that time. Remember that by default, if a detail grid is not expanded then it doesn't exist/is undefined. Also don't forget to do cleanup/destroy when needed.